# How do I place django rest nested serializer's fields to serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the following code, template is a foreign key. template is nested serializer to question serializer.

```
 [{
        "pk": 15,
        "template": {
            "question_type": 1,
            "question": "What is your age ?",
            "answer_type": 1,
            "available_choices": []
        },
        "order": 1,
        "mandatory": true
    }]
```

What I want to show is:

```
[
{
    "pk": 15,
    "question_type": 1,
    "question": "What is your age?",
    "order": 1,
    "answer_type": 1,
    "mandatory": true,
    "available_choices": []
}]
```

How do I show nested serializers data fields like this ?

This is my serializer class:

```
class TemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    available_choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = (
            'question_type', 'question', 'answer_type',
            'available_choices'
        )
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    template = TemplateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = (
            'pk', 'template', 'order', 'mandatory'
        )
```

Comment: Write a custom serializer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you defined your custom create() and update() functions on your serializer.

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    question_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='template.question_type', read_only=True)
    question = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='template.question', read_only=True)
    answer_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='template.answer_type', read_only=True)
    available_choices = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='template.available_choices', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I was trying with `serializers.Field()`.

Comment: I get TypeError: Object of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not JSON serializabl